# SQL запрос в Excel на GO, оптимизация

Tags: javascript, sql, golang

Мне нужно сформировать отчет Excel и скачать его. Данные берутся из SQL ( примерно 200 тысяч строк на 70 столбиков). Количество столбцов заранее не известно (иначе просто запихнула бы всё в структуру и норм), поскольку для нормального вывода используется pivot, без него будет примерно 20 столбцов на 1400 тысяч строк. 
Сам запрос идет примерно две минуты - плохо, но сойдет. 
Далее идет запись в каждую ячейку Excel отдельно, ибо другого способа всё это перенести я не нашла, вот он (используются 
    "github.com/360EntSecGroup-Skylar/excelize" и
    _ "github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb" // s):

```
rows, err := db.Query("[Proc]", sql.Named("param", param))
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        defer rows.Close()
 (

        colNames, err := rows.Columns()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("error fetching column names\n", err)
        }
        length := len(colNames)

        // Create a interface slice filled with pointers to interface{}'s
        pointers := make([]interface{}, length)
        container := make([]interface{}, length)
        for i := range pointers {
            pointers[i] = &container[i]
        }


        rowcol := 9
        col := 1

        for i := 0; i < len(colNames); i++ {
            xxxfile.SetCellValue(sheetName, getExcelColumnName(col)+"8", colNames[i])
            col++
        }

        // Process sql rows
        for rows.Next() {
            column := 1

            // Scan the sql rows into the interface{} slice
            err = rows.Scan(pointers...)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("error scanning sql row\n", err)
            }

            // Here we range over our container and look at each column
            // and set some different options depending on the column type.
            for _, v := range container {

                xxxfile.SetCellValue(sheetName, getExcelColumnName(column)+strconv.Itoa(rowcol), v)
                column++
            }
            rowcol++

        }
```

После записи каждая строка обрабатывается по циклу (в строке есть признак группы, в соответствии с которым она форматируется и назначается стиль)
Это дело затягивается на несколько часов, что не подходит совсем.

Как это оптимизировать? Нужно свести к нескольким минутам

Comment: Вопросы: а) `github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb` - какая версия MSSQL? б) У вас есть прямой доступ к таблицам или только через хранимую процедуру `[Proc]`? в) вы пробовали подготавливать вместо excel-файла csv-файл и затем использовать его как источник?

Comment: a) 14, б) есть, в) нет, сейчас попробую

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была, как я считаю, в том, что с библиотекой excelize я до каждой ячейки дотягивалась отдельно, т.е. нужно сделать запись в ячейку C10254, начинаем с A1 и долго ищем нужную, затем следующую так же, это и занимает кучу времени. Поняла это когда поставила логи на каждые 10000 строк, с каждой десяткой время увеличивалось.

Решение - мне помогла другая библиотека tealeg/xlsx, в которой создается строка, в ней создаются ячейки,  т.е. записываем всегда в ячейку рядом и далеко не ходим.

[Пример](https://github.com/bwmarrin/sql2xlsx/blob/master/main.go)

Answer (score 1):

## Анализ

Рассмотрим проблему  **"Как оптизировать создание "20 столбцов на 1400 тысяч строк в excel"** внимательнее:

1. БД - MSSQL 2017
2. Источник данных - хранимая процедура `[Proc]`. Доступ к исходным таблицам используемым в `[Proc]` - есть. Время исполнения: ~2 минуты
3. Используется библиотека `excelize`
4. В программе организуется цикл с обходом 20 колонок и 200 тысяч строк из исходного набора данных
5. В цикле происходит манипуляция с `getCellValue`, `setCellValue` (не совсем ясна роль `pointers` и `container`
6. Само преобразование `xxxfile.SetCellValue(sheetName, getExcelColumnName(column)+strconv.Itoa(rowcol), v)` не совсем ясно, но ясно, что не содержит каких-либо рокет-сайенс алгоритмов обработки

### Как оптимизировать `for rows.Next(){ ... }` ?

Никак. Самая быстрая операция - та, которую не исполняешь.

По исходным данным, полученным от ОПа - можно рекомендовать следующий путь:

1. Берем процедуру `[Proc]`
2. Либо изменяем ее, либо записываем вывод из нее в таблицу `insert into .. exec [Proc]`, либо делаем view/function - то, что посчитаем наиболее подходящим на уровне MSSQL
3. Создаем запрос в SQL выполняющий преобразование, аналогичное `getExcelColumnName(column)+strconv.Itoa(rowcol), v)`. Если возникают проблемы - создаем вопрос c тагами `mssql`, `t-sql` и ждем помощи коммьюнити (я лично готов помочь, я убежден, что там что-то простое)
4. Изменяем программу на голанге, оставляем в ней только `db.Query` к составленному запросу и запись в эксель файл без какой-либо обработки
5. Замеряем время исполнения, обнаруживаем, что оно стало меньше минуты.

Готов помочь в случае затруднений